# Doubt in Riesz Representation Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I am reading Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis and I am on Chapter 2. The statement of Riesz Representation says that if $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space and $I$ a positive linear functional on $C_c(X)$ (the set of complex functions with compact support). Then there is a unique positive measure ${\mu}$ on $\mathcal{B}(X)$, the Borel
$\sigma$-algebra associated with the topology on $X$, for which
$$
I(f)= \int_X f \,d{\mu} \text{ for all } f \in C_c(f)
$$
Also measure satisfies Local finiteness(i.e all compact sets have finite measure), outer regularity for all elements in sigma algebra and inner regularity for all open sets E.

**My Doubt :** Suppose I am able to find a Measure say $\lambda$ on Borel sigma algebra such that I am defining a functional $\phi$ on $C_{c}(X)$ by
$$
\phi (f)=
\int_X f \,d{\lambda} \text{ for all } f \in C_c(f)
$$
Suppose that $\mu$ be the measure correspomds to $\phi$ which I get by Riesz.
Can I conclude that $\lambda=\mu$ ?

Comment: I think they would be mutually absolutely continuous

Comment: The uniqeness part of the theorem _says_ that $\lambda=\mu$ if both measures are finite on compact sets, outer regular and inner regular on open sets. Without those extra conditions no, it's possible for $\lambda\ne\mu$; there's an example in one of the exercises.

Comment: @NickCastillo Is that just a guess or what?

Comment: @ David C. Ullrich just a guess actually

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thank you Sir. I think you are referring to exercise number 18. Suppose we are working in LCH space in which we have every open set is sigma compact and we have a Borel measure which is finite on Compact sets. Then I think we have $\lambda=\mu$.

Comment: @VaibhavKalia That exercise doesn't present a counterexample to anything, instead giving an extension of the theorem under stronger hypotheses. So I can't imagine why you think it's the one I'm referring to. I don't have the book here, so I can't give the number, but I'm talking about the exercise involving uncountable well-ordered sets (the first uncountable ordinal, to be specific).